# What could "lavender-bag ancestors" mean in Ted Hughes' "Crow Improvises"?

Tags: meaning, poetry, ted-hughes

In *"Crow Improvises"* ([text version](https://mr-stapleton.livejournal.com/284547.html)), the protagonist conjoins a list of disparate objects, where each pair of objects ignites a spark.

Putting aside the symbolic meaning of each object, it is clear to me what each object *is* - except for one:

> There was this man
> Who took the sun in one hand, a leaf in the other -
> The spark that jumped burned out his name.
> So he took his **lavender-bag ancestors** under one arm
> And his twisting dog under the other -
> The spark that flash-thumped fused his watch of all things,
> And left a black orifice instead of a time-sense.

Considering that:

- A *"lavender bag"* is a kind of [sachet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sachet?oldformat=true).
- *"lavender-bag"* is used here as an [adnoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adnoun?oldformat=true) for *"ancestors"*.

What could *"lavender-bag ancestors"* mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It popped up to me that it could be a typical Hughesean macabre way of referring to the protagonist's ancestors' cremation remains, put into a sachet bag.

This interpretation suits well to the refraining chorus of burned up objects, and also with those two lines that refer to mourning and burial:

> [...]
> The spark that banged burned out his weeper.
> So he leaned one hand on a gravestone
> [...]